# AngularJS - Dynamically add urls to $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist

Tags: angularjs

I have this snippet where I am configuring my AngularJS application to whitelist certain urls

```
angular.module("MyModule").config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
     $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(["mySite", "myOtherSite/**", "myOtherOtherSite/**"]); 
}]);
```

I have searched everywhere online and it seems because of the phases of AngualrJS (configuration and run), the provider object doesn't have access to any of the services available in angular -or my services for all that matters-.

Now due to some changes in the architecture, having the hardcoded list of URLs is no longer possible. I would like to make a REST call and then configure the application to use the URLs returned from the REST API. So I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this or if there is something that I could do override the implementation of the $sceDelegateProvider.

```
angular.module("MyModule")
       .config(['$sceDelegateProvider', 'myHTTPService', function ($sceDelegateProvider, myHTTPService) {
            myHTTPService.callSomeAPI(function (res) {
                //...someMagic stuff here
                $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(magicUrls);
            });
}]);
```